# Origen y uso del término dompedro

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Revisando palabras de forma aleatoria, vi como en la palabra *don* entra la locución *don pedro* que remite al sustantivo [*dompedro*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E7aV3YB). Su significado es:

> 2. m. coloq. orinal.

Según el mapa de diccionarios, esta definición aparece en 1925, pero el origen no queda muy claro. ¿De donde procede el origen de este término? ¿En qué países se usa hoy día el mismo?

Comment: La primera vez que oí esta palabra fue a mi profesor de Historia del Arte, refiriéndose al asiento que usa un personaje del Jardín de las Delicias (a la derecha en esta imagen: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/telediario/jardin-delicias-esconde-partitura-musical/2402939/). Según él, en ocasiones lo usaban los reyes y señores durante las audiencias, para no tener que levantarse (se tapaban con un manto, eso sí), y de ahí el nombre. Pero, claro, no es una fuente fiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues espera que la cosa se pone aún más divertida. La primera vez que aparece la palabra es en el diccionario de la RAE de 1884 con la siguiente definición:

> **Dompedro.** m. Dondiego.

Bien, habrá que añadir por qué el cambio de nombre de Diego a Pedro a la lista de preguntas a resolver. Sigamos con *dondiego* entonces. En 1803 se definía como:

> DONDIEGO. s.m. Lo mismo que ARREBOLERA por planta.

¿Mande? ¿Arrebolera? Según el diccionario de Autoridades (1726) significa:

> La salserilla ò tacita pequeña en que tienen las mugéres el color roxo que se ponen en la cara.

Hum. Interesante, pero una "tacita pequeña" no exactamente un orinal, aunque se acerca. Habrá que ver cuándo han ido variando las definiciones. Volvamos a 1803, la definición de *arrebolera* (por planta) es:

> Planta bien conocida en los jardines y otras partes, la qual echa unas flores à modo de...

No, esto no es. Callejón sin salida. Volvamos a la definición de *dompedro*, que debió tener un significado diferente al de *dondiego*. Este nuevo significado entró en el diccionario en 1899:

> **Dompedro.** m. fam. Bacín, 1ª acep.

Siendo "bacín" el "vaso de barro vidriado, alto y redondo, que sirve para recibir los excrementos mayores quando se descarga el cuerpo". Vale, ahora sí, esta es la acepción que buscamos.

Así que recapitulando, tenemos una flor, el dondiego, que también es conocida como dompedro y que acabó dando nombre al orinal (nótese que *dondiego* no llegó a tomar este significado). Hora de consultar otras fuentes... vaya, no hay nada en el Fichero General que aclare esto. Y no hay ningún caso de "dompedro" en el CORDE con el significado de "orinal", no puede ser... ¿La hemeroteca de la BNE? Tampoco.

La cosa se está poniendo fea y creo que ante este panorama no nos va a quedar más remedio que especular. Posibilidades que veo:

- Que de alguna forma haya una conexión entre la arrebolera (como "continente del arrebol") y el orinal, cosa que veo poco probable.
- Que se usaran las flores de dondiego (o dompedro) para disimular el olor depositado en los orinales (tampoco he encontrado nada que establezca esta conexión).
- Que se llamara "dompedro" al orinal por mera similitud entre estos y las flores de dompedro, como podría parecer según estas capturas:

[image: Dompedros]

Nótese que *dompedro* también puede hacer referencia a un mueble, tipo mesita de noche, que albergaba dentro un orinal. Recuerdo que mis abuelos paternos tenían estos muebles en su dormitorio. Sería algo parecido a esto:

[image: Dompedro u orinal isabelino]

Hay quien dice que en realidad el nombre *dompedro* hace referencia a este mueble, y no al orinal en sí, y que se llaman así porque el rey [Pedro I el Cruel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_I_de_Castilla) fue el primero en utilizarlos (he visto esta afirmación en varios sitios, posiblemente todos copiados de la misma fuente desconocida). No he encontrado nada que lo confirme.

Comment: And of course Dom Pedro was the first emperor of Brazil, not I suspect that he is responsible any more than Pedro the Cruel.